# Rails / Sitemap_Generator: Subdomain sitemaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my app which features subdomains using the [sitemap_generator gem.](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator)  However, I'm getting an error with my code:

`the scheme http does not accept registry part: .foo.com (or bad hostname?)`

My sitemap.rb:

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.foo.com"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/foo/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemaps/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::WaveAdapter.new

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add '/home' 
end

Customer.find_each do |customer|
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://#{customer.user_name}.foo.com"
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = "sitemaps/#{customer.user_name}"
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
    add '/home'
  end  
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of this gem.

I am fairly certain that the problem is with one of the customer user name's containing a character which is not allowed in a URL.  A simple test with simple names works e.g.:

```
%w(bill mary bob).each do |customer|
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://#{customer}.foo.com"
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = "sitemaps/#{customer}"
  SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
    add '/home'
  end  
end
```

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator#generating-multiple-sitemaps). This helped me a lot!